# Python - Creating class instance within superclass method

Tags: python, scope, inner-classes

I am trying to create a class in the superclass

I have a superclass in SuperTest.py:

```
class SuperTest():
    def func(self):
        return Test2()
```

And test.py

```
from SuperTest import *

class Test(SuperTest):
    def create(self):
        return self.func()

class Test2(SuperTest):
    pass

test = Test()
print test.create()
```

Then I have an error `NameError: global name 'Test2' is not defined`.

Is it possible to do that? How to handle the scope? As I know I can't mutually import the classes recursively.

I will be getting some class names in the superclass function. It is important for me to dynamically create the class in it.

Comment: You can't import stuff "recursively", meaning a submodule can't use classes/functions from the "main program". You would have to do `from test import Test2` in `SuperTest.py` - otherwise it won't know about `test2`. In `test.py` you could also do `builtins.__dict__['Test2'] = Test2` -- **note that this is not the way you should do things** (this will make Test2 "truly global" :)

Comment: Define `Test2` in SuperTest.py.

Comment: I would like to get some class name in string and create them dynamically, e.g. eval('Test2') or eval('Test3') and so on (and there are many of them) when calling the subclass create method. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
class SuperTest(object):
    def func(self):
        from Test import Test2 
        return Test2()
```